# How to play the advertising before video play using jwplayer

Tags: php, jquery, jwplayer

I need to play some dynamic ads before play the video  using jwplayer .

I have following code to play video and ads

```
 $res = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$res .= '<VAST version="2.0">';
$res .= '<Ad id="static">';
$res .= '<InLine>';
$res .= '<AdSystem>Static VAST Template</AdSystem>';
$res .= '<AdTitle>Static VAST Tag</AdTitle>';
$res .='<Impression>http://example.com/pixel.gif</Impression>';
$res .= '<Creatives>';
$res .= '<Creative>';
$res .= '<Linear>';
$res .= '<Duration>00:00:08</Duration>';
$res .= '<TrackingEvents>';
              $res .='<Tracking event="start">http://example.com/pixel.gif</Tracking>';
              $res .='<Tracking event="firstQuartile">http://example.com/pixel.gif</Tracking>';
              $res .='<Tracking event="midpoint">http://example.com/pixel.gif</Tracking>';
              $res .='<Tracking event="thirdQuartile">http://example.com/pixel.gif</Tracking>';
              $res  .='<Tracking event="complete">http://example.com/pixel.gif</Tracking>';
              $res  .='<Tracking event="pause">http://example.com/pixel.gif</Tracking>';
              $res  .='<Tracking event="mute">http://example.com/pixel.gif</Tracking>';
              $res  .='<Tracking event="fullscreen">http://example.com/pixel.gif</Tracking>';
              $res  .='</TrackingEvents>';
             $res  .='<VideoClicks>';
               $res  .='<ClickThrough>http://www.longtailvideo.com/</ClickThrough>';
              $res  .='<ClickTracking>http://example.com/pixel.gif</ClickTracking>';
            $res  .='</VideoClicks>';
            $res  .='<MediaFiles>';
              $res  .='<MediaFile type="video/mp4" bitrate="300" width="480" height="270">';
               $res  .='http://example.com/uploads/myPReroll.mp4';
               $res  .='</MediaFile>';
             $res  .='</MediaFiles>';
            $res  .='</Linear>';
         $res  .='</Creative>';
       $res  .='</Creatives>';
     $res  .='</InLine>';
   $res  .='</Ad>';
 $res  .='</VAST>';

jwplayer('primcast.com').setup({
  file: 'http://localhost.com/test/uploads/videos/test-video-107.mp4',
  primary: 'flash',
   advertising: {
    client: 'vast',
     tag: '<?php // echo $res ;?>'
  },
  width: 480,
  height: 270
});
```

Here  $res variable contains the xml format of the my ads video file .
 But  Its play only video , not play ads . How can I  fix this .

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any of that code with JW Player. Assuming you have an Ads license of our player, all you need to do is to include the VAST ad tag URL in the advertising: {} block's tag: '' parameter:

```
jwplayer('your_div_id').setup({
    file: 'your_video_URL',
    advertising: {
        client: 'vast',
        tag: 'your_VAST_URL'
    }
});
```

You can also include your ad tags directly in the player's configuration using your JW Player account dashboard.

Please see http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1431665-basic-preroll-video-ads for more details.

Comment: Can I give direct  url :- https://s3.amazonaws.com/demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/jwplayer-30s.mp4  in  advertisting tag .